# Vue. Отрисовываются цветные квадраты из независимых объектов. Как перемешать эти квадраты между собой с сохранением количества и цвета?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Есть `List1` который состоит из нескольких объектов `item1` `{number:12, color: #333333}` и `item2` `{number:16, color: #ffffff}`. свойство `number`(количество квадратов) и `color` (цвет этих квадратов) задаются пользователем. Квадраты в компоненте отрисовываются через `n in ITEM1.number`, а цвет квадратов задается через `:style="{background: ITEM1.color}`. Вопрос в следующем. Как по нажатию кнопки перемешать между собой квадраты с данными из объектов `item1` и `item2` с сохранением количества и цвета указанных пользователем?

Comment: 1. `n in ITEM1.number` - наверное `item in items`? 2. Правильно было бы приложить код к вопросу. 3. А в чём у вас сложность, какие идеи есть и что не получается?

Comment: Вы отрисовываете квадраты без состояния или каки либо id, так как item1 это просто параметры клонов без какой либо привязки. Так же что значит перемешать между собой. Приведите пример.

Comment: По поводу `item1` - это то, что получилось реализовать, что работает и реактивно связывает данные от юзера (чекбоксы с цветом и количеством квадратов без кнопки записи новых данных - реализовал через `v-model`) и их отображение. Пробовал запись в массив данных от пользователя с `id` и последующего вывода - не получилось реализовать, не понял как построить массив, как организовать запись.

Comment: У вас проблема никак не связана с глобальным состоянием. Вам надо создать массив и  *рандомно* заполнить его элементами равным кол-ву в `Item 1`,   `Item 2`,   `Item 3`,  ... Причём элемент массива должен хранить параметры отрисовки, например цвет.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ и рекомендации. Есть ли какие-то замечания по моему коду, структуре, логике?

Comment: Я думаю мои мысли выходят за рамки сообщества. Думаю у вас есть TeamLead и он вам всё расскажет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      red_square: {
        color: 'red',
        count: 3,
      },
      green_square: {
        color: 'green',
        count: 5,
      },
      squares: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.squares = [
        ...Array(this.red_square.count).fill({
          color: this.red_square.color
        }),
        ...Array(this.green_square.count).fill({
          color: this.green_square.color
        }),
      ].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  }
})
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container grid-list-xl>
        <v-row>
          <v-col v-for="(e, i) in squares" :key="i" class="square" :class="e.color">
            {{ i }}
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```